# Query the size of a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

While working with the NDK Camera interface I stumbled upon the problem that a SurfaceTexture can request a defaultSize which can be overridden.
I wanted to get the actual size, but SurfaceTexture offers no way to query that.
So instead I tried this:

```
// this runs directly after SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage
GLfloat width, height;
glGetTexLevelParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &width);
glGetTexLevelParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &height);
```

Which worked flawlessly on a Mali system but returns GL_INVALID_ENUM on an Adreno system.
The [extension's description](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt) does not introduce GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES as a valid paremeter for GetTexLevelParameter so I assume I was just lucky on the Mali system.

Is there any way to query the size of an GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES in OpenGL ES (3.1)?